# objective-c: draw line on top of UIImage or UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios4

How do I draw a simple line on top of a UIImage or UIImageView?

Comment: Can you be more specific on your use case?  Different needs would precipitate different ways of accomplishing your task.

Answer (score 15):

The following code works by creating a new image the same size as the original, drawing a copy of the original image onto the new image, then drawing a 1 pixel line along to the top of the new image.

```
// UIImage *originalImage = <the image you want to add a line to>
// UIColor *lineColor = <the color of the line>

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size);

// Pass 1: Draw the original image as the background
[originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

// Pass 2: Draw the line on top of original image
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, originalImage.size.width, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [lineColor CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// Create new image
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Tidy up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Alternatively**, you could create the line as a `CAShapeLayer` then add it as a subview to the `UIImageView` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370557/draw-line-using-cgcontext/5370656#5370656)).

Comment: I want to draw any symbols or any objects on uiimage or uiimageview, just like we are doing signature. Is there any way ?

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 3.0

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size)
    originalImage.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setLineWidth(2)
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: originalImage.size.height - 2))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: originalImage.size.width, y: originalImage.size.height - 2))
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.strokePath()
    let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```