# How to insert image on UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiview

The code below prints a line on a UIView. I just want to know the code that I would write to be able to insert an image on top of the view.

```
import UIKit

class draw: UIView {
    var line = UIBezierPath()
    var line1 = UIBezierPath()

    func grapher() {
        line1.move(to: .init(x:0, y: bounds.height / 6))
        line1.addLine(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height / 6))
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()
        line1.lineWidth = 2
        line1.stroke()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        grapher()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simple add background image in view why you can draw bezierpath?

Comment: You looking for [`UIImageView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview)? What does the line drawing have to do with inserting an image?

Comment: please check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905941/objective-c-draw-line-on-top-of-uiimage-or-uiimageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905941/objective-c-draw-line-on-top-of-uiimage-or-uiimageview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to add image on view. Please use below code.

```
let imageName = "yourImage.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
//Imageview on Top of View
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: imageView)
```

If you want to draw specific shape then go with `Core Graphics`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics

https://cocoacasts.com/drawing-shapes-in-swift-with-paintcode/

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/drawing-shapes-core-graphics-tutorial-ios10

Comment: bringSubview() is now bringSubviewToFront()

Answer (score 14):

Add `UIImage` on the view layer

```
let myLayer = CALayer()
let myImage = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
myLayer.contents = myImage
myView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
```

Add `UIImage` as a subView

```
let image = UIImage(named: "star")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
myView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on `Swift 4`

This function should be called in/after viewDidAppear to let view render

```
func addArrowImageToButton(button: UIButton, arrowImage:UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "my_arrow_image") ) {
    let btnSize:CGFloat = 32
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: arrowImage)
    let btnFrame = button.frame
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: btnFrame.width-btnSize-8, y: btnFrame.height/2 - btnSize/2, width: btnSize, height: btnSize)
    button.addSubview(imageView)
    //Imageview on Top of View
    button.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
}
```

and call it this way in viewDidAppear

```
self.addArrowImageToButton(button: myButtonObject)
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what code to write in viddidappear.

Comment: @SamBurns I have updated my answer for the same. `myButtonObject` needs to be instance of button that needs to have arrow image. `my_arrow_image` needs to be replaced with the name of your arrow image.