# How to insert image over uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, layer, subview

The code below prints a line on a UIView. I just want to know the code that I would write to be able to insert an image on top of the view. Many people will [point to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180635/how-to-insert-image-on-uiview) but it does not work. I have tried it several times. The code I tried below is having no effect.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var canVasView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myLayer = CALayer()
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "star")?.cgImage
        myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        myLayer.contents = myImage
        canVasView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of adding as layer, try to add as subview.

Comment: Where do you add `canVasView` as a subview to the view controller's view? And why not use a `UIImageView` instead of dealing with layers?

Comment: Could you show us a picture of one of the examples?

Answer (score 2):

First you create a `UIImage` from your image file, then create a `UIImageView` from that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  //  var canVasView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageName = "star.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

   // Finally you'll need to give `imageView` a frame and add it your view for it to be visible:

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
   // canVasView.addSubView(imageView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)

  }

}
```

Comment: This is not working. I have attached my code via dropbox link dropbox.com/s/ksnshbj40vn78qf/draw.zip?dl=0. Can you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `canVasView` as Subview to `UIViewController` view and add the image in assets. [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0WKd.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var canVasView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myLayer = CALayer()
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "graph")?.cgImage
        myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
        myLayer.contents = myImage
        canVasView.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)

        self.view.addSubview(canVasView)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I have attached my code via dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ksnshbj40vn78qf/draw.zip?dl=0. Can you look at it?

Comment: sorry for the delay. add image in assets rather than adding direct. See the updated answer.